# Mounting encrypted external device with conflicting LVM names

Tags: linux-mint, lvm, data-recovery, luks, disk-encryption

I got myself a new hard drive and installed the most current version of Linux Mint. Now I wanted to transfer the files from the old disk (I had no recent backup) but there are several issues

- the LVMs' names are conflicting (Linux Mint uses `mint-vg` for the name) from my new internal system and the external drive
- the disk itself is encrypted
- my `/home` is encrypted as well
- the new drive is encrypted as well

How can I recover my data?

Answer (score 6):

### Mounting the drive

(I use a USB-casing for SATA drives, you might as well install the drive in your PC)

When encrypting the disk while installing Mint the drive will contain a partitioning scheme (using `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`) such as

`/dev/sdb1 -> Bootable, about 500M in size, Id 83, Type "Linux"
 /dev/sdb2 -> Not-bootable, rest of your disk's capacity, Id 5, Type "Extended"
 /dev/sdb5 -> Not-bootable, rest of your disk's capacity, Id 83, Type "Extended"`

After you found the partition try to mount it using

`sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 exthdd`

Where `exthdd` can actually be anything, but it must not exist under `dev/mapper`, so you might check this first.

You will be asked for your passphrase for the partition, so have it ready. If you lost this, there is no help for you...

Running `lsblk` again you should see something like `mint--vg-root` and `mint--vg-swap_1` under `exthdd`.

### Handling the conflicting LVM names

When the device is unlocked via `cryptsetup luksOpen`, run

`sudo lvscan`

which will show you something like

`inactive     '/dev/mint-vg/root' [UVW GiB] inherit
 inactive     '/dev/mint-vg/swap_1' [XYZ GiB] inherit
 ACTIVE       '/dev/mint-vg/root' [ABC GiB] inherit
 ACTIVE       '/dev/mint-vg/swap_1' [DEF GiB] inherit`

As you can see you have `mint-vg` twice under `/dev` directory, which leaves you to access only one of these (in my case it pointed to the external hard drive).

Fortunately the underlying volume groups are distinct by an ID (VG UUID). We can retrieve these IDs running

`sudo vgdisplay`

which will show you something like this (output abbreviated):

```
--- Volume group ---
 VG Name        mint-vg
 ...
 VG Size        UVW GiB
 ...
 VG UUID        UVW-ID

 --- Volume group ---
 VG Name        mint-vg
 ...
 VG Size        ABC GiB
 ...
 VG UUID        ABC-ID
```

In my case I was able to solve the difference by looking for the size of the hard drives, of course you can check the ID of your current VG before mounting the external drive.

Now that we have the ID (UVW-ID) we can rename the VG using

`sudo vgrename UVW-ID newvgname`

You should get a

`Volume group "NAME-OF-UVW" successfully renamed to newvgname`

Checking `lsblk` should reveal you with two entries under `sdb5`, `newvgname-swap_1` and `newvgname-root`.

### Decrypting and mounting your home directory

If you check `/dev/mapper` now, you will find two new nodes

`/dev/mapper/newvgname-root
 /dev/mapper/newvgname-swap_1`

Run

`sudo mount /dev/mapper/newvgname-root /your/mount/point`

and check the result

`ls /your/mount/point` - voilà, you should now have access to the device.

Now go to the `/home` diretory and look for the hidden directory `.ecryptfs`.
Inside you should find a directory `user` - where `user` is the user name you are looking for.

Now run

`sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /your/mount/point/home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/`

You will be prompted for the password for the account of `user`:

```
INFO: Found [/your/mount/point/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: _
Inserted auth tok with sig [...] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success! Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.ABCXYZ]
```

Yet, if you lost this password, there is little to no hope for you.

You can now go to `/tmp/ecryptfs.ABCXYZ` and see the contents of the home directory.

### Unmounting

Unmount everything in the reverse order.